# My UV maps overlap

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I marked my seams properly but when I press U my pieces overlap. As you can see painting the turban paints the face at the same time. You can see in the UV editor on the right the pieces are overlapping. (ignore the beard I am redoing the particle system when all this is done.) [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, Blender's native "Unwrap" is very reliable. Unfortunately, you haven not actually marked your seams properly.

The parts of your UV map are overlapping because there is too much "material" to fit in the flat area. If you think about it like taking a piece of clothing apart, there are lots of situations where you'll have to cut the pieces completely apart in order to lay them flat without them overlapping. The same is true here. You have seams in a lot of the right places, but it's just not possible to lay everything out flat in one big piece without having stuff overlapping.

The solution is to make your existing seams longer so that pieces are cut completely apart, instead of trying to keep them attached to each other.

For example, if you run a seam completely around the base of the ear to cut it all the way off, then you can run whatever seams you need to make just the ear unfold flat.

Run a seam around the front part of the face so that it comes completely off, and that'll unfold flat.

Don't be afraid to create "islands" (i.e. UV parts that are not attached to the rest of the UV map) if that's what it takes to make it all flat. You just have to be careful where you put those seams so that they aren't too obvious once it's textured.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I dont understand sorry, the turban is a completely seperate island to the face yet when I paint one it appears on the other and the islands clearly overlap

Comment: Interesting... It'd be helpful if you could show a larger image of your UV layout specifically. Especially if you can show it without the image behind (so that we can see the lines).

Comment: I did cut it up a bit more and it seems to work now, thank you